# When I run migration, config.assets is not working in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-7

I recently upgraded my application from rails 6.1 to rails 7.0.3 and I am facing some issues after that.

Following lines are defined in my `development.rb` file:

```
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
```

But when I run migration I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `assets' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00007f6c2d5eb0c8 @root=#<Pathname:/app>
```

Although migration runs fine after commenting the above lines. I am not really sure why this is happening. Please let me know if anyone has any idea about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you removed the `sprockets-rails` gem in favor of `webpacker`.

`config.assets` comes from this gem and is no longer needed if you stopped using this.

[options explanation on github](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/README.md)

Note that the `config.assets.raise_runtime_errors` is no longer available in recent sprocket versions and is always enabled.